# How i can add custom markers and increase its size to look normal

Tags: android, kotlin

I am adding custom markers to my map but the size is much smaller than the default marker.

On my research for how to add a custom icon as marker i found this code to parse a drawable to a BitmapDescriptor and others that looks just the same.

```
fun bitmapDescriptorFromVector(context: Context, vectorResId: Int): BitmapDescriptor? {
    val vectorDrawable: Drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, vectorResId)!!
    vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, vectorDrawable.intrinsicWidth, vectorDrawable.intrinsicHeight)
    val bitmap: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        vectorDrawable.intrinsicWidth,
        vectorDrawable.intrinsicHeight,
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    )
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    vectorDrawable.draw(canvas)
    return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap)
}
```

i tried to change de vector values and the bit map size values, but didn't worked.

this is how i add the marker

```
mMap?.addMarker(
                    MarkerOptions()
                        .position(riderLocation)
                        .title(rider.name)
                        .icon(
                            bitmapDescriptorFromVector(requireContext(),R.drawable.ic_restarant_rider_assigned)
                        )
                )
```

[image]

Comment: Hi did you add this code in onMapReady?

Comment: No, i set this markers after a request.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the height and width of your Icon from **24dp** to **48dp** in the xml file and it becomes with the same size of the default icon, here is my icon :

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="48dp"
    android:height="48dp"
    android:tint="#0037FF"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
        android:pathData="M12,2C8.13,2 5,5.13 5,9c0,5.25 7,13 7,13s7,-7.75 7,-13c0,-3.87 -3.13,-7 -7,-7zM12,11.5c-1.38,0 -2.5,-1.12 -2.5,-2.5s1.12,-2.5 2.5,-2.5 2.5,1.12 2.5,2.5 -1.12,2.5 -2.5,2.5z" />
</vector>
```